# Exclude node_modules directory for TypeScript compilation, but allow one individual subdirectory

Tags: node.js, typescript

The whole node_modules directory can be completely excluded for TypeScript compilation using this `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "target": "es6"
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

But how can I allow one individual sub-directory under node_modules, like `node_modules/app`, to still get compiled? I know that the `files` section can be used to specify individual files and override the `exclude` section, but that can get unwieldy very quickly, especially when used alongside `exclude`. Is there a better option?

For a bit of context, I am planning to put application-specific modules in the node_modules/app directory, so I can require them without using relative paths:
`var m = require("app/module1")`
versus
`var m = require("../../module1")`).

Comment: if you're willing to upgrade to typescript 2, you can use glob patterns.

Answer (score -1):

Just `require` the module/subfolder that contains your code. Explicitly importing a file/directory overrides the global "exclude" in a sense that it will be picked up by tsc.
Also set `"moduleResolution": "node"` if you haven't already.