# Exclude directory from MSBuild Typescript compilation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, typescript, msbuild, csproj

I've got an ASP.NET MVC / Angular2 project which uses MSBuild to compile my Typescript files.  The project contains the entire Angular2 source code and its NodeJS dependencies in addition to my Angular2 code (`app.ts`, etc.).

My problem is that MSBuild is compiling every Typescript file in the entire solution - including the Angular2 source code, its dependencies, and my `app.ts` code.  I want to exclude any Typescript files located in the `node_modules` folder from compilation.

My understanding is that `tsconfig.json` files are generally responsible for excluding certain files or directories from being compiled (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39692304/exclude-node-modules-directory-for-typescript-compilation-but-allow-one-individ)), but that the `.csproj` files in ASP.NET project will supervene on `tsconfig.json`.  So I'm trying to figure out what to write in the `.csproj` file to tell MSBuild and `tsc.exe` *not* to compile specific files or folders.

The [MSBuild Typescript compiler options documentation](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options-in-msbuild.html) is not helpful.  Does anybody have any insight on this?

Comment: Are you not using a tsconfig.json file? I ask because it's unclear if you are and have overridden it's `exclude: []` by including the files in the .csproj or what exactly is going on.

Comment: @silentsod I am using a `tsconfig.json` file.  My original assumption is that the `.csproj` functions similarly, and that the `.csproj` supervenes on whatever is in the `tsconfig.json` file - so I'm assuming there's some sort of XML statement I can include in the `.csproj` file to exclude Typescript files from compilation on project build.  *However*, I looked through the detailed MSBuild output and it looks like it locates the `tsconfig.json` file and presumably reads from it - so I'm not sure what `.csproj` is doing behind the scenes.

Comment: A .csproj file should only have your application files listed for compilation, if you have included anything from node_modules I would exclude that folder from your project. You ought not to be publishing anything directly out of node_modules anyways.

Then, in your tsconfig.json you would have your `exclude: ['node_modules', 'typings']` (if you are using @types instead of typings then obviously you won't have a typings folder).

Comment: @silentsod +1 and I suspect you're right about the "don't publish `node_modules`" point - it was not my decision to publish the entire Angular2 source code along with the rest of the project.  However, wouldn't it be necessary to publish and package  `node_modules`, as it contains the `@angular` folder (also assuming the inclusion of the `@angular` directory is necessary in order to compile the Angular2 source code)?

Comment: I'm going to cohere some comments into an attempt at an answer, you are not the first ASP.NET guy with these questions. I have a bit of a head start as I'm at a further point in the discovery & learning process. It's really not the same as angularjs, plain TypeScript, or plain JavaScript in terms of writing things out. NPM brings an entire set of incidental things with it from what I can tell.

Comment: Incidentally if you want to include your second question about publishing and packaging node_modules in your original question it makes my reply seem less crazy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A .csproj file should only have your application files listed for compilation, if you have included anything from node_modules I would exclude that folder from your project. This is to prevent any weird compilation attempts by VS's TypeScript Compiler from that angle. Then, in your tsconfig.json you would have your `exclude: ['node_modules', 'typings']` (if you are using @types instead of typings then obviously you won't have a typings folder). Same thing, just preventing the compiler from touching those folders.

Example tsconfig.json with the exclude in place:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules", "typings"
  ] 
}
```

To take things a step further and hopefully save you some time when you decide to deploy your app out I think you should consider the following:

When it comes to deployment or publishing - while you could publish the entire folder and it's subfolders it is immense and time consuming. There was another, similar, question where attempting the node_module publish locked up a dev's box and eventually crashed his VS.

Trying to manually find and include all the dependencies is a) very time consuming and b) likely to drive you crazy making sure everything is included and only once. I had considered doing such a thing and rejected it.

For better or worse npm and node_modules mixed in with Windows and ASP.NET means the path of least resistance and most gain is learning an additional set of tooling to bundle up your application. The documentation is a little shakey if you're, say, dumb enough to use Webpack 2 (in beta, which I did) but the results are that you can have your npm script task, gulp task, or whatever build out only what you need for deployment. I have a 150+MB node_modules folder and I end up with a 1MB (production) set of JS files at the end of the day (tree shaking is great and I love it).

The tools for consideration are SystemJSBuilder with GulpJS (if you're already using SystemJS this is a natural path to take), Rollup (this had an issue with TypeScript interfaces and the issue I filed was listed as known and without a good fix), Webpack, and I'm sure there are more that I'm forgetting and probably even tried.

There are a number of tutorials for each available, and each has a healthy community around them. The Angular team has a webpack tutorial which is a good start if you take that route: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/webpack.html

The SystemJS builder team has their own documentation: https://github.com/systemjs/builder but I believe you'll need to combine it with gulp documentation to learn how that pieces together.

Rollup is a bit less developed so I used their documentation http://rollupjs.org/guide/ and examples such as https://github.com/manfredsteyer/angular2-aot-webpack2-rollup

Comment: Thank you very much for the extremely insightful answer.  Trying to piece everything together: is the suggestion here to use GulpJS to compile/group all of the relevant Angular2 stuff (source files; custom modules and components) into the project directory prior to building/publishing?

Comment: Prior to publishing, definitely, as this makes the publish/deploy much easier and far more lightweight. For your development it's arguably not necessary unless you start encountering serious performance issues with loading.

I don't know what your directory structure is but the way we went was, with our production build, to put our bundled files in an entirely different folder than they are for development which means switching where our <script> tags are pointing to. We start in a Razor view and I put in a check for the debugger being attached to do it automagically.

Answer (score 1):

I also needed to add this line to my csproj file.

```
<TypeScriptCompile Remove="ClientApp\node_modules\**" />
```